# Which Xcode macros can be used to check the OS version of the compiling computer?

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

Building an iOS application using Xcode 4: 2 developers, one with 10.6.8 and one with 10.7. In 10.7 the NSURLConnectionDelegate interface is explicit: it is defined and can be added to the interface declaration. In 10.6.8 however, it isn't defined and a compile error is generated (*NSURLConnectionDelegate: cannot find protocol declaration*). This error can be fixed by simply removing the declaration. I'm looking for a compiler macro that identifies which OS version the code is being built on so I can modify the code to be compatible with both OS versions. Something like:

```
#if _CURRENT_OS_X_IS_10_7_OR_HIGHER
@interface appDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
#else
@interface appDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate> {
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `NSAppKitVersionNumber` and/or `NSFoundationVersionNumber17_0`

**EDIT**

As you compile for iOS, you won't be able to use any macro coming from a Mac OS framework. Your only chance is the Xcode/GCC predefined macros.

You can check them with:

```
gcc -arch i386 -dM -E - < /dev/null | sort
```

This seems interesting:

```
__ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__
```

Comment: Unfortunately those don't appear to work using `#ifdef` statements: this is for an `@interface` declaration, so it must be compile time, not run time.

Comment: Check in NSApplication.h. You also got macros for each versions.

Comment: Sadly, that appears to be OSX only: my actual project is an iOS project (iPhone app), and there is no `NSApplication.h` header in the Foundation.framework tree.

Comment: Wait... You want to use OSX specific macros for iOS??? Shouldn't you check the iOS version?

Comment: No, no. It is an iOS app, but I want to include one header if the build is taking place on 10.7, and exclude it on earlier builds. This means I can build it on my 10.6.8 Mac Mini, and my partner who uses 10.7 on his shiny new Macbook can also build it.

Comment: No way to have the OSX macros then, since you are building for iOS. Look for the Xcode predefined macros. Looks like your only chance.